# On ARM, how to save the sp_usr register if a thread running in user mode is interrupted

Tags: linux, arm, mode

As we know, ARM has some banked registers such as **sp** and **lr**. In other words, while in **irq** mode, **sp_usr** (and **lr_usr**) is invisible, that is, shadowed by **sp_irq**. So, my question is how the interrupt handler saves **sp_usr**. Some people might think that this is unnecessary because **sp_usr** will automatically remain unchanged during the handling of the interrupt since it's invisible and inaccessible in **irq** mode. However, this is not always the case. Consider the following scenario:

a) Thread A is running in user space.

b) An external interrupt occurs.

c) The handler runs, and finds that Thread B which has a higher priority now has got the resource it has been waiting for, so decides to reschedule.

d) Saves the context of Thread A. Now Thread B runs, first in **SVC** mode, then back in **user** mode. **This is just the moment when the value of sp_usr is overridden by thread B.**

e) Thread B calls something like **sleep**. Thread A will resume running from the point where it was interrupted.

So, if **sp_usr** was not saved when thread A was interrupted, how would thread A restore its context?

Comment: Obviously, SP & LR need to be stored and later restored. They should be stored when the CPU is in either User or System mode.

Comment: You should clarify which ARM architecture version you are looking at, this may affect the detail of the answer.

Comment: @Sean Houlihane  I'm using ARMv7 Cortex-A9

Answer (score 1):

sp_usr must be saved before the context switch to thread B, then when thread B goes to sleep and the context of thread A is restored. If sp_usr for thread A is not saved then it is lost. Generally in a context switch the current sp is saved in the current tasks control block. When the new task is selected the sp is restored from the new tasks control block.

See this thread: [ARM. Access user R13 and R14 from Supervisor mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/324704/arm-access-user-r13-and-r14-from-supervisor-mode/324928#324928)

A lot of this does depend on which arm architecture you are using!